# how to get many strings between two strings or two characters

Tags: java, string

I have this text tokenized as follows:

> ∅habbaz∅abdelkrim∅habbaz∅abdelkrim∅habbaz∅abdelkrim

I want to get every string between the character `∅`. I have tried the following:

```
ArrayList<String> ta = new ArrayList();
String test=t2.getText();
String str = test;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("∅(.*?)∅");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {

    ta.add(matcher.group(1));

}    
t3.setText(ta.toString());
```

It's supposed to give me:

> [habbaz,abdelkrim, habbaz,abdelkrim, habbaz,abdelkrim]

But it's giving me only:

> [habbaz, habbaz, habbaz]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with the regex solution, try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("∅([^∅]*)");
```

This pattern will match a ∅ followed by any number of non-∅, which should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split`:

```
String input = "∅habbaz∅abdelkrim∅habbaz∅abdelkrim∅habbaz∅abdelkrim";
String[] tokens = input.split("∅");
```

This will produce an array of those strings that are between your delimiter. Note that the first string in the array will be `""`, the empty string, because your input string starts with the delimiter `∅`. To avoid this, take a substring of the input right before you split (`if (input.startsWith("∅")) {input = input.substring(1);}`), or process the resulting tokens to exclude any empty strings.

To turn the tokens into your `ArrayList`, use the following:

```
ArrayList ta = new ArrayList<Element>(Arrays.asList(tokens))
```

Or you could just write:

```
List ta = Arrays.asList(input.split("∅"));
```